# Basics of Java : Project Euler problems

Tags: java

Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

Find the sum of all the even-valued terms in the sequence which do not exceed four million.

My code:

```
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    int z;
    int sum = 0;


        for(int i = 0; i <= 4000000; i++)
        {
        z = x + y;
        x = y;
        y = z;
        if(y % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum = sum + y;
        }


    }
    System.out.println(sum);

}
```

That outputs `1110529254` but, the correct answer is `4613732`.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Let me know if the discussion here does not address your problem, but this is what's happening.

Comment: You are iterating 4 million times. You are not checking if the number in the sequence exceeds 4 million.

Comment: *"even-valued **terms** in the sequence which **do not exceed** four million"* means that the Fibonacci *value* should not exceed 4 million, that that you should go through that *many* Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @chrylis I don't think the duplicate is on point. See my comment above.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77124/project-euler-2-fibonacci-sequence/77174

Comment: Indeed, changing the `for` loop to `while (z <= 4000000)` fixes this for me. Note that in C# at least you'll have to initialize `z` to 0.

Comment: *Solution:* Replace `for(int i = 0; i <= 4000000; i++)` with `while (y <= 4000000)`

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I tried something similar and it worked for me.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you, my code is now producing the correct result.

Comment: @Andreas Good call, I didn't parse the problem statement correctly at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does iteration 4 million times but it does not check the sum of all the even-valued terms in the sequence whether do not exceed four million or not.

Below you can find my variant of getting sum of all the even-valued terms in the sequence which dont exceed for million.

```
 public class Example_1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

      int x = 0;
      int y = 1;
      int z;
      int sum = 0;

      while (true) {
          z = x + y;
          x = y;
          y = z;
          if(y % 2 == 0) {
             sum = sum + y;
          }
          if (sum >= 4000000){
              break;
          }
      }
      System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
  }
}
```

The answer which I get from this code is `4613732` as we expected.